# How to show dynamic values on thermometer D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, d3.js

This is the sample code of thermometer using D3.js. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rockroyal/uhn5bxah/)

I have created a web page of thermometer whose values are coming dynamically on every time interval of 1sec. Following is the function

```
setInterval(function(){ getNewValue() }, 1000);

function getNewValue(){
  var currentTemp = getLastValue();  //Get latest values from database.
 // remaining js
}
```

On each time interval, it creates new thermometer chart rather than only updating chart with new values.. I've been unable to figure out that how to solve this..?

Plz anyone help me.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/venkatnehatha/uhn5bxah/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what do you need

`setInterval(function() {
$('#thermo').empty(); //add Jquery and this
  showNewValues();
}, 1000);`

https://jsfiddle.net/uhn5bxah/2/

Comment: It's working great. Thank you very much for your help.